# ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object'

Tags: python, keras, ubuntu-18.04, importerror, conv-neural-network

I'm doing an image classification using cnn in ubuntu 18.04 terminal while training I got  error message like this:

```
from .utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object'
```

When I'm tried to check keras version using the below code in the terminal same error is showing.

''' 
       python3 -c 'import keras; print(keras.*version*)' 
   '''

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: `from .utils.generic_utils` implies that the import is from a file in the current directory. Is that file present? Read more about relative import [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).

Comment: The python file is present in the current directory..I don't understand whats wrong in it, I'm beginner to python.When I'm trying trying to check keras vesion same error is showing.